# Command Line Java + Jar Files

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line, jar

So far, I've only ran simple apps from the command line via `javac filename.java`. Now, I've created an application in NetBeans and I really want it to run from the command line. I am using an external .jar file in NetBeans that is a program dependency. How do I go about running this from command line? Furthermore, how would I go about creating a shortcut so that I all I have to do is double click and the program would start running?

EDIT: I've gotten it to compile, but it still won't run. It gives me this 
`Error: Could not find or load main class JavaApplication1` even though the .java file, class file, and .jar file are all there.

EDIT2:  I ended up solving this by going back to netbeans, doing a "build and clean" and using the .jar file that netbeans generated to run the project.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compile/run with a dependency on a jar, the -classpath modifier is used. For example:

```
javac -classpath <path-to-jar> filename.java
```

Comment: Basically, my path looks like this: `C:\RunJava\filename.java`, and I also have the .jar file inside the the same directory. So, would it be `javac -classpath <C:\runjava\filename.jar> filename.java`?

Comment: Without the <>, but yes :).

Comment: Thats only compiling, afterwards you should run it with: java -classpath C:\RunJava\filename.java filename (paths depend on the current location in the file directory)

Comment: Ok, so the first command executed successfully, as no errors were thrown. However, shouldn't it produce a class or something? I still can't run it.

Comment: It should produce a filename.class in the same directory as filename.java. To rule out path-issues I'd suggesting navigating to C:\RunJava\ and run: `javac -cp filename.jar filename.java` followed by `java -cp filename.jar filename` (cp is shorthand for classpath)

Comment: ok. I got it to produce the class. However, running `java -cp filename.jar filename` gives me the error `could not find or load main class` even though I can clearly see it there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74734/discussion-between-g-d-and-tammert).

Comment: Solved. I ended up going back into netbeans and doing a "build and clean" which then generated the .jar file for the project.  Then I was able to execute the .jar file. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To start a java executable jar application:

```
 java -jar executable.jar
```

If you haven't an executable jar but only a single class or some class not packaged in a jar file you have to use the following command:

```
java MyClass
```

Where `MyClass` is the class with the `main` method.

Comment: Should I package the netbeans project into a .jar file? I've been trying to run just the .java file. If so, how would I do this?

Comment: You can also run a single java class using the command "java classname"

Answer (score 1):

To execute a jar from the command line you can run the following from the command line:

```
java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar
```

To have a shortcut execute the jar file make sure it runs the same command as above.